# is there a s3 move function in the aws sdk for node

Tags: aws-sdk

I was looking at the documentation for the aws sdk and the s3 client and saw that there was a mv command with the s3 client.

If I wanted to move an object from one s3 bucket to another, is there a move function, or do I have to use copyObject followed by a deleteObject using the sdk?

The documentation for the aws sdk only shows delete and copy.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't a move operation in the S3 API, so you're correct that it's standard practice to copy an object, then to delete it.

Comment: It should be noted, deleting from s3 incurs a [small fee](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/).